Manage role's resources in Entra ID - Azure Portal
I'm building a React web app, and I'd like to manage the role access with Entra ID.
In Entra ID you can add a new App Registration and into it, create App Roles to later assign to users (in App Enterprise section).
My doubt is, can I map roles with resources/actions/permissions?
My idea is, once the user is logged (with the Azure SSO) get in the jwt token the user roles, and for each of it, the actions/resources. And with this actions/resources render the menu/botons, etc.
I tried several thinks, but I can get how to create custom resources/permissions/actions and associate to the App Role.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To manage roles, resources, and permissions in Entra IDfor your React web app, you need to define app roles and permissions within your Azure AD app registration, and then assign those roles to users or groups.
Create App Registration

Define App Roles

Repeat the process for any additional roles you want to create
Assign Roles
Enterprise applications -> Users and groups

Add user/group
Choose the role you want to assign , in my case admin and assign.

and accordingly configure your react app to use the roles
ensure you have installed the required libraries for Azure AD authentication
npm install @azure/msal-react @azure/msal-browser jwt-decode

Configure MSAL in Your React App:
// src/authConfig.js
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "45b931fc-3b3a-4e0a-a7ec-119143ea23da",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9329c02a-4050-4798-93ae-b6e37b19af6d",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
};

export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

Provide the MSAL instance to your React app
// src/index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { msalInstance } from "./authConfig";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <App />
    </MsalProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

Use the msal-react and jwt-decode libraries to handle authentication and extract roles from the JWT token:
// src/App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

function App() {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const [roles, setRoles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
      instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ["api://45b931fc-3b3a-4e0a-a7ec-119143ea23da/.default"],
        account: accounts[0],
      }).then((response) => {
        const decodedToken = jwtDecode(response.accessToken);
        setRoles(decodedToken.roles || []);
      });
    }
  }, [accounts, instance]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to My App</h1>
      {roles.includes("admin") && <AdminComponent />}
      {roles.includes("user") && <UserComponent />}
    </div>
  );
}

function AdminComponent() {
  return <div>Admin Content</div>;
}

function UserComponent() {
  return <div>User Content</div>;
}

export default App;

This allows you to manage role-based access control (RBAC) effectively in your web application.
Here are some references that may be helpful:

Add app roles to your application and receive them in the token
Create custom roles to manage enterprise apps in Microsoft Entra ID
Overview of role-based access control in Microsoft Entra ID


Thanks for the response! But I'm not want to render component in base of the roles. I'll render components in base of resources/permissions for each rol.
